# How to get index value from parent element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, indexing

I have list:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
    <li>fourth</li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to get the index of the `<li>` I just clicked.

What I tried is something with `index()` but it doesn't work as expected.
Am I missing something?

Here is my code:

```
console.log($('.nav li').index());
```

Clicking on the 2nd `<li>` should return "2" (or 1, if the index is starting with 0)

This here is my click-function:

```
$('.nav .hasChild > a').click(function(e) { 
    console.log($('.nav li').index());
    ....
});
```

The "hasChild"-class is not important in my case

Comment: How do you handle click event?

Comment: Why would `$('.nav li')` return the LI just clicked? It returns ALL the LIs.

Comment: I updated the code and added my click-function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.nav .hasChild > a').click(function() {
   var indexVal = $(this).closest('li').index();
   console.log(indexVal);
});
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you :)
Will accept this answer in a few mins, as soon as I can :)

Comment: @DasSaffe I don't see any `a` in your HTML. How comes that this code works?

Comment: Well, an a is nested inside a ".hasChild" class. But in my case i need the parent <li> number, which should only trigger, if a specific `a` is clicked

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
$('.nav .hasChild > a').click(function(e) { 
    console.log($(this).parent("li").index());//this holds the current element reference which is clicked

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am missing something with the extra classes but surely it is as simple as;

```
        $('.nav li').click(function() {               
           console.log($(this).index());
        });
```